# How to Get all unread mails from Exchange server 2007 using Exchange web service?

Tags: c#

How to Get all unread mails from Exchange server 2007 using Exchange web service?

Answer (score 6):

```
int unreadEmailCount = 0;

        SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));

        ItemView view = new ItemView(999);

        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view);
        unreadEmailCount = findResults.Items.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, [click here to read more](http://omegacoder.com/?p=454)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Active Dir ID", "password", "domain name");

        service.AutodiscoverUrl("user@domain.com");

        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(
            WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
            new ItemView(10));

        foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
    }
```